# How to get an image to go to a corner and automatically adjust its size

Tags: html, css

How can I get CSS to use both height and width to resize an image?
Example, because I don't even understand myself (btw the corner I choose is the top right):

- if the width is greater than the height, the image would be on the left
- if the opposite, the image would be on the top

And as the window's shorter side resizes, the image would resize too. Also, I'm sure there's a JS solution to this, but I am looking for all CSS, and the image is a square if that somehow helps.

Example that works as if the width was always the longer side:

```css
img{
  position: absolute;**
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500"></img>
```

This is here to test Temani Afif's answer

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500"></img>
```

Comment: max-width:100%;max-height:100% ? (and remove the height:100%)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, almost.... all that is wrong is that it doesnt get any bigger than the images size

Comment: and what is missing?

Comment: @TemaniAfif , I just edited the comment

Comment: is the ratio of your image always known?

Comment: @TemaniAfif always.... the images and dimensions will change, but they will only be squares. 1:1 (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your image is always a square you can do the following:

```css
img{
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500"></img>
```

Comment: by any chance is there a way i can do the opposite of this?

is there a way i can use up the leftover space instead?(div)